# Error occurred running Grails CLI: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, command-line-interface

I am trying to run grails commands from the CLI, but I keep getting the following error:

```
`C:\Users\nxf82701\Desktop>grails create-app testApp
OpenJDK Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`
```

I checked my PATH, and it is set correctly with `grails` pointing to the appropriate `bin` directory where grails is installed on my machine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this very well written article to solve my issue - https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art032#comments. It now works like a charm!